# C# winform database server explorer control

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, database-connection

Is there a known component/control that can open a database server browser/explorer window, such as one you would get when connecting to a mssql database server using the sql server manager, or another way to let the user browse to a database server, select the database and supply credentials to sign on.

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/kjbartel/ConnectionDialog

Comment: Yes, that exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Ed Elliott 's answer
There is a nuget package for
[DataConnectionDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/)

`Install-Package DataConnectionDialog`

oh my- a lots of details
https://github.com/kjbartel/ConnectionDialog/blob/master/ReadMe
and for the real answer - this works for me.